# creating csv file in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am trying to create CSV file for below code. When i run the code initially it usually create the csv file. For same code it not creating CSV file. Let me Know What issue is

```
If counter = 1 Then
                counter = 0
                Dim headerText = ""
                Dim csvFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "test.csv")
                If Not IO.File.Exists((csvFile)) Then
                    headerText = "Date,TIME ,Current, "

                End If

                Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
                    If headerText.Length > 0 Then
                        outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
                    End If
                    Dim date1 As String = "24-10-2014"
                    Dim time1 As String = CStr(TimeOfDay())
                    Dim Current As String = CStr(distance)
                    'Dim x As String = CStr(CDbl(date1 + "," + time1 + ",") + distance)
                    Dim x As String = date1
                    outFile.Write(x)

                End Using
            End If
```

Comment: "When i run the code initially it usually create the csv file. For same code it not creating CSV file" - Can you try and make your question clearer?

Comment: @5uperdan for same code @ intial stages it used to create CSV file. But Now it not creating . Once i copy the all script new project it started working. Thanks for the help